# How to find a value based on a variable in a column?

Tags: r, subset

I want to find a value, based on another value in a data.frame in R. I can do this way for instance:

```
myDataFrame[myDataFrame$weight==83, "Student.Name"]
```

This will find student names whose weight are 83.

However, my real situation is that, the column name "weight" is stored in a variable, which changes as time goes on. How can I achieve the same effect? I tried this below, it doesn't work.

```
data[data$colName==83, "Student.Name"]
```

Comment: Thanks for editing for better reading.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data[data[, colName] == 83, "Student.Name"]`. `[` is much better suited for programmatic use than `$`.

Comment: Sorry. I clicked wrong. should be up arrow! Please correct.

Comment: I think you should just explain that `$` can`t evaluate variables.

Comment: @user697911, correct your click yourself?